# set equivalence with expect.js

Tags: node.js, testing

I use `expect.js` and I'd like to test for set equivalence

```
Error: expected [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 0 ] ] to sort of equal [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1 ] ]
```

^ this should be true.

I've found [this](http://community.service-now.com/blog/slightlyloony/4113), but how do I integrate it into `expect.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cheat by sorting the array.. (below is coffescript)

```
 describe 'test', ->
  it 'should match', ->

    a = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 0 ] ]
    b = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1 ] ]

    expect(a.sort()).to.eql b.sort()
```